# Do burst/close burst attacks "splash" around corners?

Tags: dnd-4e, powers, line-of-sight, line-of-effect

I know that blasts require LoS in 4e and that bursts require line of effect between the target square and the creature using the power but one my players asked if a burst would hit diagonally around a hard corner. My first thought was a hard no, but then remembered reading somewhere about bursts "splashing" around corners decided I needed some clarification. What are the rules for burst attacks and corners?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

From my reading of the PHB, both require line of effect from their origin square, and neither require line of sight (p272):

> A blast affects a target only if the target is in the blast’s area and if there is line of effect from the origin square to the target.

and

> A burst affects a target only
>   if there is line of effect from the burst’s origin square to the target.

You are probably remembering a rule from 3.5 that allowed [spreads](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/magicOverview/spellDescriptions.htm#area) to do exactly what you describe.  But 4e is a bit simpler; you only check whether there's line of effect from the origin of the spell.  (I'm sure there are exceptions, but those will be explicitly called out.)